# Displaying a JOption Pane from a functions class

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have two classes one that I have in my program. One I have drawn my Graphical user interface and another that has methods to be executed by buttons in GUI class. Basically it's a program to add records to a database. When I click button register it calls the functions class to execute add to database method. In the add to database method I need to add a `jOption` pane to display successful or not.. How do I ho about it .

I have tried

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"successful");` the code is not working since it is not in the  GUI class

Comment: Can you show how are you inserting data to your database ?

Comment: Perhaps try: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(javax.swing.FocusManager.getCurrentManager().getActiveWindow(), "successful");`

Answer (score 0):

> the code is not working since it is not in the GUI class

You can pass the "frame" as a parameter to your "functions" class.

Then the "functions" class can use that value as the "frame" for the JOptionPane.